# Can we develop application in iOS which can enable vibrate when I touch to screen like in samsung?

Tags: ios

A very accurate way to transfer touch motion from the touchscreen of the smartphone to the vibrator.

I simple example is this app on the Samsung Galaxy:
http://i1.wp.com/techsplurge.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Galaxy-S3-Tips_EEE3/custom-vibration.jpg

If you think it can poassible please help me to know the library and way to do this application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible, yes. Would Apple allow it, maybe.

If your application uses the vibration function too much, Apple is likely to reject it and ask you to reduce vibration. As a rule, vibration should only be used for alerts. I'm unable to find the official documentation on this [but it is well known](https://www.google.com/search?q=apple+rejection+vibration&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=apple+rejection+vibration+too+much).

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@import AudioToolbox; // Import AudioToolbox

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // Vibrate
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
}
```

Comment: It sounds like the OP wants global vibrate controlled outside of the app. Which can't be done.